# Getting response of body as {size:0} in googleAPIs

Tags: node.js, express, google-api

I am querying the gmail.googleapis.com for Gmail data, but in response the body always returns {size:0} though there is a data in snippet. (Adding screenshots for better clarity).

[image]

Here is the code which I am working with

**controllers.js**

```
const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  process.env.REDIRECT_URI
);
async function readMail(req, res, next) {
  const actualMessage = []
  try {
    const url = `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=is:unread&maxResults=1`;
    const { token } = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();
    const config = generateConfig(url, token);
    // console.log(config);
    const response = await axios(config);

    let data = await response.data;
    // console.log(data.messages);
    data.messages.map(async (mes) => {
      const actualUrl = `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/${mes.id}`
      const actualConfig = generateConfig(actualUrl, token);
      const actualResponse = await axios(actualConfig);

      let actualData = await actualResponse.data;
      console.log(actualData);
    })
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.send(error);
  }
}
```

**generateConfig**

```
const generateConfig = (url, accessToken) => {
  return {
    method: "get",
    url: url,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken} `,
      "Content-type": "application/json",
    },
  };
};
```